# Keeping up-to-date with Bioconductor packages

Tags: r, updates, bioconductor

I want to install the latest R/Biocondutor version on a PC running Windows 7 64 bit. I am thinking of installing only R 64-bit in, e.g., a folder C:/R in order to have a unique library folder with full writing permission.
I read the recommendations here https://www.bioconductor.org/install/
It appears that one R version might correspond to more than one Bioconductor version, and also that newer package version might be released for the same Bioconductor version. 
I am wondering whether, in order to stay up-to-date, is it enough to periodically run first biocLite("BiocUpgrade") and then biocLite()?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org). `biocLite("BiocUpgrade")` will only transition between Bioconductor versions within an R version -- for the current R-3.3.* series, you'll stay up-to-date with Bioconductor for version 3.3 (current) and 3.4 (due in October), after that your R will be too old for the current Biocoductor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bioconductor updates within the same R version is what I was wondering about